# How to configure eslintrc and add React to eslint (with airbnb, typescript) without create react app

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-typescript, eslint-config-airbnb

My project is not using create-react-app. I am upadting my Eslint. How do I add React properly to the eslintrc.js file?

Currently I have this in the `extend` property:

```
extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    // "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    // "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    // "plugin:eslint-comments/recommended",
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:jest/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
```

For example now eslint throws error:

> Function component is not a function
> declarationeslintreact/function-component-definition)

How can I just use arrow functions for my React components etc?

Answer (score 0):

```js
"react/function-component-definition": [
  2,
  {
    namedComponents: "arrow-function",
    unnamedComponents: "arrow-function",
  },
],
```

"react/function-component-definition": [
2,
{
namedComponents: "arrow-function",
unnamedComponents: "arrow-function",
},
],

Just add these line in your eslintrc.js file. This only allow you to add arrow function.

Comment: where does the `2` stands for? Enable? And what about my eslintrc.js config? Is `'plugin:react/recommended',` to correct way here adding React  to eslint without create-react-app?